# Azure Web App Unable to find assembly 'Entity Framework'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I'm trying to publish a project to an Azure Web App via Visual Studio 2015. This is an MVC 4 targeting Framework 4.6.2. The publish procedure claims in VS2015 to have finished successfully, however, when the browser is launched to display the published site, it errors out with a 502 error (bad gateway/proxy) on the favicon.ico file. Obviously, that's not what's really happening.

I downloaded my `eventlog.xml` file from the Web App and looking at the error being reported, it's claiming that it's unable to find assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0...'. However, I see the EntityFramework.dll contained within the project `bin` folder. But, just to see if it made any difference, I tried using Kudu to install EntityFramework from NuGet, as well as doing a nuget restore using the `packages.config` file that was successfully pushed up to Azure. All that did was restore a ton of files where I didn't need and the same error remains.

Has anyone else seen this issue and have any recommendations on how to resolve it? I'm not sure what else I can post to give a clearer picture of what's going one...it's not like there's any code or source, and the `eventlog.xml` file shows little more than the YSOD error message for a missing assembly.

Please, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your packages.config file in the web project contain the reference to Entity Framework package? Sometimes if you use Resharper or some other tools to add references the file packages.config doesn't get updated and when you deploy your app nuget does not restore the file.

Comment: @KarelTamayo Yes, the packages.config file holds a line item for both EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer, and the packages were added to the project via the Package Manager Console, rather than via adding a reference in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this in the past - if you read the error message carefully it says it can't load that assembly *or some of its dependencies* - so it may well be another dll that's missing from your application.

Use the Console blade in the portal (or the separate Kudu site and console if you prefer) to compare the bin folder contents with that on your dev/test environment and see what's missing - if you stick to using nuget packages then you shouldn't be able to go far wrong, but I think I still had problems a while ago with EF when I didn't reference the EF libraries directly from the web app, but only from a repository assembly that was referenced from the web app.

If you're not using Nuget and referencing the dependencies directly make sure the referenced dll's "copy to output" properties in VS are set correctly, such that the dll's end up being copied to your project's bin folder and included in the package that gets deployed to Azure.

Comment: I'll take a look at that and see about comparing the project bin folder contents with those that were published up. Also, I've seen the issue described with EF and a separate repository assembly. In fact, that's the scenario we have here, but I do know that EF was installed via Package Manager Console to both the repository project and the web app project. I've also verified that all assemblies that are non-NuGet do have their copy to output set appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out this one was one of those "that's not the real issue" error messages. Thanks to Russell and Karel. You input led me to verify a few things and make sure I had all things referenced properly.

Here's what I found out...our DEV SQL VM is turned off on the weekends to conserve resources (aka $$$). After sending all files from my local `bin` directory via FTP, I browsed to the site and received the same error. Downloading the logs, however, showed that I couldn't reach the db server using Named Pipes. Whoops...one of the connection strings (in the repository project) had not been set to the FQDN, so it wasn't using TCP/IP for the connection.

I fixed that, published the site, turned **ON** the sql server, and now the site is working as expected.

Moral of the story, make sure you have all connection strings set properly.